# Status bar backgroundColor

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, statusbar

I am using ios 7 I want to set stauts bar background image.
I have done this but still it is not changing anything:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //change this to match your navigation bar
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
}
```

Comment: 'not changing anything' isn't really descriptive for us to help, is it on the screen? try changing its colour to see if the issue is the adding or the position

Comment: It looks okay to me. Check if that code is even executed, and if it is, whether `self.window.rootViewController.view` is not nil.

Comment: how to check that is it null or not? @Scott

Comment: check this link: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: check this one     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works, but you have to modify it a bit. here is what it should look like..

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    //change this to match your navigation bar or view color or tool bar
    //You can also use addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor]; or any other color
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1.png"]];
//here you are adding the image as the background image
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```

don't forget to import your image to the project. now i have just plugged in the above code in application didfinishwithoptions of the app delegate, but you should be able to use the same if you want different views using the same.
[image]

Comment: I have done this code...but still not displaying...may be because after then I have set bartintcolor for navigation bar...so I think this override my old code...possible?

Comment: @vivek, the tint color of the nag bar should not interfere with the status bar. they are different. just created a sample project and applied the code above and the result is as shown on the screen shot

Comment: @vivek, here is what i did. plugged the above code in app delegate and also changed the nag bar tint in tableview class as follows: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0f green:51.0/255.0f blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]; as you see in the screen shot, they both work differently.

Comment: sorry I have just seen your reply and now I am on leave...I will try your code after crishmats...and then let you know it will work or not

Comment: If I have to hide this custom view in one of the View controllers, will I be able to hide it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this like .h file

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *statusBarBackground;
```

and in .m file

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    self.statusBarBackground = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, 20)];
    self.statusBarBackground.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"statusbar_bg"]];
    [self.statusBarBackground makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

add this to your controllers

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
        if (viewBounds.origin.y == 0) {
            CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
            viewBounds.origin.y -= topBarOffset;
            self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add the this function and lets see

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things.

(1) Open your `info.plist` and set `"View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO`

(2) add these lines to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{   
    self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];     

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 0,self.window.frame.size.width-20,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    } else
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: @vivek UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque set black

Comment: but I want to display image in status bar

Comment: In ios 7 there is only UIStatusBarStyleLightContent